# Why does my H2 query run very fast in Squirrel but very slow in my Java code?

Tags: sql, jdbc, h2, database-performance, squirrel-sql

I created a query on an H2 database that uses left outer joins on 7 tables.
There are  indexes on each table that reference the join columns.
When I cut and paste the sql and execute it in Squirrel, the execution time is very fast, maybe 10 milliseconds.
But when I execute the same query in my Java code with a prepared statement, it takes over 3 minutes.

I notice when my Java program is executing, h2 is creating a temp file that grows to almost gig.
Obviously, this is not occurring in Squirrel in 10 milliseconds.

I've tried to make the Squirrel environment exactly like the one my Java code runs in: Both use the same H2 database, the same database url, the same driver, the same credentials, the same JVM.

The table sizes range from about 350K rows to 10K rows.
The total columns in the select statement is about 40.

Does anyone know how Squirrel executes this query so fast?

Thanks!

```
jdbc:h2:C:/EclipseWorkspaces/workspace36/MyH2DB;FILE_LOCK=NO;

select
table1.primarykey1,
table1.primarykey2,
table2.a_column,
 (8 more columns)
table3.a_column,
 (8 more columns)
table4.a_column,
table4.a_column,
table5.a_column,
table5.a_column,
table6.a_column,
 (13 more columns)
table7.a_column,
 (13 more columns)
from table1 
left outer join table2 on table1.primarykey1 = table2.primarykey1 and table1.primarykey2 = table2.primarykey2 
left outer join table3 on table1.primarykey1 = table3.primarykey1 and table1.primarykey2 = table3.primarykey2 
left outer join table4 on table1.primarykey1 = table4.primarykey1 
left outer join table5 on table1.primarykey1 = table5.primarykey1 
left outer join table6 on table1.primarykey1 = table6.primarykey1 
left outer join table6 on table1.primarykey1 = table6.primarykey1 
left outer join table7 on table1.primarykey1 = table7.primarykey1 
left outer join table7 on table1.primarykey1 = table7.primarykey1

PreparedStatement ps = h2connection.prepareStatement(query.toString);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery() //Takes over 180 seconds, but only 10 milliseconds in Squirrel
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer, just suggestions for things to check. Are you sure squirrel is not caching the data somehow? Try making an inconsequential syntax change and running again. I don't think it would process the data volume you have in 10 milliseconds. There is no `WHERE` clause, so won't you be getting a lot of data back? I assume the results are the same from both?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did try a where clause -- where table1.primarykey1 = 31417114 and Squirrel found this single row in .031 seconds.  I'm guessing this has something to do with the way Squirrel opens the database and maybe caches the indexes.  The fact that H2 is creating a large temp file makes me think it is not using these indexes properly.

Comment: Here's the answer: call the setMaxRows() method of the PreparedStatement. In Squirrel client the default in the editable field is 100.  What a no-brainer!!